# Enter contacts using workflow in Accounts

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, customization

I have a situation where I am creating an Account record from a contact using a workflow, but I would like to have the Contact section in the Account be filled with the Contact from who I am creating that Account record using a workflow. How do I enter the contact in it using Workflow.

[image]

I need the contacts related to the Account show up here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you have to do is:

Once you have created the account, you need to update the contact and assign the parent account referencing the newly created account